# Is it possible to pass an event to a parent coming from a child in Vue 3

Tags: events, vuejs3

I have many components that include others, and a deep component needs to send an event to a higher one. That component will `$emit('eventName', some, properties)`

The component's parent will have in the template, something along

```
<child-component @event-name="handleEvent" />
// ...
methods: {
    handleEvent ($event, some, properties) {
        this.$emit('eventName', some, properties)
    }
}
```

This seems tedious.

I was hoping there is a way the template could pass the even without touching it?

Ideally, this would work out of the box :

```
<component-child @event-name="$emit" />
```

But it's not because $emit can't guess the name of the event.

So, I tried the following:

```
<component-child @event-name="$emit('eventName', ...parameters)" />
```

But every time this event is emitted (like if there are 4 nested components that do that), the parameters increase by one every time, adding the $event of the current event.

How can I `$emit` an event to a parent in an elegant way by keeping the arguments in the proper place?

Comment: I think in this case it would be better to just use [provide/inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#provide-inject) instead of events. In the docs it is described as a way to share data with components below but you can also share an object with some callback. It's easier with Composition API tho as you don't need to care about `this`

Comment: I thought provide/inject worked from parent down to children? Moreover, it is related to an even that is thrown, whereas provide/inject works as passing data, am I correct?

Comment: Maybe a store could help in this case. Either go full blown with Vuex or in my opinion it is enough to have one global reactive object which you import in each component that needs access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best suggestion so far, happy to have a better one:

```
<child-component @event-name="(some, properties) => $emit('eventName', some, properties)" />
```

That's better to read.